# Problems setting up a new quarkus project on Mac

Tags: macos, maven, quarkus, java-11

I'm a newbie to Quarkus, and falling at the first hurdle of trying to set up a new Quarkus project on my Mac. I've used homebrew to download openjdk and maven - the versions are here:

```
openjdk version "21.0.2" 2024-01-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 21.0.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 21.0.2, mixed mode, sharing)

Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.9.6/libexec
Java version: 21.0.2, vendor: Homebrew, runtime: /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/21.0.2/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "13.5.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "Mac"
```

When I go to run an example setup I was given I get errors. The command I'm running is:

```
mvn io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.7.1.Final:create \
    -DprojectGroupId=org.example \
    -DprojectArtifactId=uuid-generator \
    -DclassName="org.example.UUIDResource" \
    -Dpath="/generate-uuid"
```

The terminal output comes back with the following:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< org.apache.maven:standalone-pom >-------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus:2.7.1.Final:create (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.267 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-03-24T21:31:43Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.7.1.Final:create (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.7.1.Final:create failed: A required class was missing while executing io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.7.1.Final:create: org/eclipse/aether/connector/basic/BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.7.1.Final
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/Users/hilbert/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/platform/quarkus-maven-plugin/2.7.1.Final/quarkus-maven-plugin-2.7.1.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/Users/hilbert/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-bootstrap-core/2.7.1.Final/quarkus-bootstrap-core-2.7.1.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/Users/hilbert/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-bootstrap-app-model/2.7.1.Final/quarkus-bootstrap-app-model-2.7.1.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/Users/hilbert/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-fs-util/0.0.8/quarkus-fs-util-0.0.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/Users/hilbert/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.4.3.Final/jboss-logging-3.4.3.Final.jar
...
```

If I try using changing the example cmd to reflect the version of maven installed - i.e. 3.9.6, I get a different error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/quarkus/platform/quarkus-maven-plugin/3.9.6.Final/quarkus-maven-plugin-3.9.6.Final.pom
[WARNING] The POM for io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:jar:3.9.6.Final is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/quarkus/platform/quarkus-maven-plugin/3.9.6.Final/quarkus-maven-plugin-3.9.6.Final.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.730 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-03-24T21:36:45Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.9.6.Final or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:jar:3.9.6.Final (absent): Could not find artifact io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:jar:3.9.6.Final in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

I'm running this on an intel Mac running Ventura 13.5.1.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It’s the version of quarkus you want, not Maven. That version looks … old. Indeed - 2.7.1 is from late 2022; maybe try a more recent vintage? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-maven-plugin

Comment: @BoristheSpider, that was the info I needed! Changed it to from 2.7.1.Final to 3.5.0 and have a build success. Thanks for your help.